# Unable to apply function to selected columns in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[[1,0],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1],[2,3],[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1]]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
```

[image]

I want to apply the below functions to selected columns in the data frame:

```
def item_exclude_all(list1):
    from itertools import groupby
    out = [i[0] for i in groupby(list1)]
    return out

def fl(x):
    new = []
    for i in x:
        new.append([i[0], i[-1]])
    return new
```

I did the following operation by applying "fl" function, which worked without error:

```
df.apply(lambda x : fl(x) if x.name in ['C', 'E'] else x)
```

[image]

But when i'm trying to apply the other function "item_exclude_all", function is not getting applied to the selected columns.

```
df.apply(lambda x : item_exclude_all(x) if x.name in ['C', 'E'] else x)
```

I'm trying to understand what could be the issue here in the above code.

[image]

Comment: _function is not getting applied to the selected columns._ What does that mean, exactly? Can you explain what the function is meant to do?

Comment: what the function is meant to do?? Please go through the function item_exclude_all() mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `.apply()` inside the first `.apply()`. This is because the `item_exclude_all()` function should be applied over each row, not over the entire Serie.

```py
df.apply(lambda x : x.apply(item_exclude_all) if x.name in ['C', 'E'] else x)
```